# Show the size of file before upload...?

Tags: javascript, php

I need the `php` to work with javascript... :|

I want the user to upload only max 5MB files, but `PHP` detects it only after the upload is done...
example:

```
if ($_FILES["ftu"]["size"] > 5242880) {
        echo "<br /><font color='#FF4747'>Sorry, but maximum size of the uploaded file must not exceed 5MB</font>";
}
```

It works, but it echoes only after the file is actually uploaded... and I don't want it...
Another option is to check it with javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#upheadinp').bind('change', function() {
            if(this.files[0].size > 5242880){
            $('#uploadspan').html("<font color='#FF4747'>Max file size is 5MB</font>");
            }
        });
    });
```

Yeah so this works too, but it's only to show the error message...
How could I merge `php if function` with this `javascript function`?

My expectations are something like:

```
<?php
if("<script>(this.files[0].size)</script>" > 5242880){
echo "error";
}
?>
```

Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: You can't merge PHP with Javascript. They execute in different places at different times.

Comment: use the js to disable the form submit, after the file select if the size is to large ?

Comment: Although you can't merge the two you can have your _JavaScript_ fire an _AJAX_ call to your php server which says the file size and waits for a response before you do another request to upload your file. This does increase the server load as it would mean 2 requests per upload rather than just 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above comments are obviously correct. JS is a client-side scripting and PHP is server-side. The two do not directly interact for obvious reasons.

The best solution would be to prevent the form from being able to submit. This would achieve what I interpret to be what you are looking for. A way to prevent someone from submitting in addition to the PHP prevention. Proper programming convention would dictate any user submitted data (text, uploads, etc) should be validated both on the client and server ends. Never trust client data and never assume it was properly validated.

```
$("theformyouareusing").submit(function(e) {
    if($('input[type=file]').files[0].size > 5242880){
         e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

You may also want to have a check for older browsers that do not support `.files.size` and decide how you want to handle those cases.

For additional security, you should add these lines into your php.ini:

```
post_max_size = 5M
upload_max_filesize = 5M
```

Comment: @Dave Correct; however, like I said above, never trust client-side validation and ALWAYS perform server-side validation as well

Comment: The `post_max_size` setting specifies the maximum size for a post, including any uploaded files and any other fields that might go along with them. Setting the `upload_max_filesize` to the same value could result in a file that is just within the maximum upload limit being rejected because the accompanying data take the post over the maximum post limit.